# Translate a batch function into a rolling function in julia

Tags: algorithm, julia

I need help translating this batch function that operates on a vector of data:

```
data = rand(100)

alpha = 0.123
output = Vector{Float64}(undef, length(data))
fill!(output, NaN)
for i in range(2, length(data))
    if isnan(output[i-1])
        output[i] = data[i]
    else
        output[i] = output[i-1] * alpha + data[i]
    end
end
output
```

Into a rolling function that gives one value per call.
This is my attempt:

```
local out
if length(output) <= 1 || isnan(output[end-1])
    out = data[end]
else
    out = output[end-1] * alpha + data[end]
end
push!(output, out)
out
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for an iteration method. Here is an example of that:

```
import Base.iterate

struct Out
    data::Vector{Float64}
    output::Vector{Float64}
    alpha::Float64
    maxiters::Int
    function Out(vlen = 100, alph = 0.123)
        return new(rand(vlen), fill(NaN, vlen), alph, vlen)
    end
end 

function Base.iterate(o::Out, state=(1,0.0))
    i, out = state
    if i <= o.maxiters
        out = out * o.alpha + o.data[i]
        o.output[i] = out
        return out, (i + 1, out)
    else
        return nothing
    end
end

for j in Out(4, pi^(-pi))
    print(j, " ")
end
```

Prints (eg) `0.566943067603886 0.3660295347293361 0.8476879530266289 0.6744241657998808`

Answer (score 0):

You are already calling it differently, might as well make it really different and drop the entire output array, since you really only need the last value;

```
process(previous, alpha, datum) = previous * alpha + datum

function main(alpha, data)
    output = 0
    for d in data
        output = process(output, alpha, d)
        println(output)
    end
end

data = rand(100)
alpha = 0.123
main(alpha, data)
```

Comment: I would rather do it the way I have it due to other reqs.